# server that spawns clients automatically on remote computers

Tags: c, linux, windows, tcp

I am developing code for automation testing. Automation is based on client_server.Both client and server code written in C language. I have one server and 3 clients(these clients perform same job) all running on different pcs. I need to manually run first server and then all three clients. These three clients establish connection with server and then automation starts. Now I want to automate starting these clients. What exactly I want to accomplish is to run the server and server by itself starts these three clients(the names/ip.address of these pcs where clients will be running are fixed) automatically by itself. All I have is I know the ip.addresses of pcs,users at those pcs and passwords(login authentication details). How to make this happen. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is authentication information then you need to look at using ssh for linux and rcmd for windows.  Both of these will allow you to access the remote machines and start clients.

Although you should probably consider using Windows services and linux daemons, as they are the standard ways of running these items.

Comment: thanks...I want to write some code that is platform independent

Comment: You won't be able to write platform-independent code across both Linux and Windows for what you want to do.  You could install a common programming language on both types of client (for example, python) and write in that but you're always going to have some sort of OS-specific code when you're working at the level of starting and stopping processes.

Comment: you also won't be able to compile platform-independent code in C.  +1 for scripting languages here.  You might consider using a scripting language which you can write your own C extension for, such as Ruby or Python.  Also, these languages have built in frameworks for automation testing, so you can leverage your favorite xUnit style framework.